# neo4j-shell on windows does not accept square brackets

Tags: windows, shell, neo4j

I have installed neo4j on windows 10 and try to copy my LOAD-CSV-Commands into the neo4j-shell. I open the Command-Prompt of neo4j and start the neo4j-shell.

The import of the nodes works fine but when i try to copy the following line into the neo4j-shell:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/neo4j/CC/autor-streitschrift.csv"
AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
// WITH line LIMIT 50
MATCH (from {id:line.Autor}), (to {id:line.Streitschrift}) create from-[:AUTOR_VON]->to
RETURN count(*);
```

... the square-brackets are not coppied:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/neo4j/CC/autor-streitschrift.csv"
>  AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
> // WITH line LIMIT 50
> MATCH (from {id:line.Autor}), (to {id:line.Streitschrift}) create from-AUTOR_VON->to
> RETURN count(*);
62 ms

WARNING: Invalid input 'A': expected whitespace, [ or '-' (line 4, column 72 (offset: 195))
"MATCH (from {id:line.Autor}), (to {id:line.Streitschrift}) create from-AUTOR_VON->to"
                                                                        ^
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

I have reproduced this on a windows7-machine.

Thanks in advance for any hints,

Andreas

Comment: what happens if you copy&paste the statement from neo4j browser to an editor (e.g. notepad) a do another copy&paste from there to neo4j-shell?

Comment: I have the commands in an editor and it doesn't work when copying directly to the neo4j-shell. Copy to the browser works,

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's awfully late, but in my case I was able to enter square brackets using Alt+91 and Alt+93. That's on Windows 7 using a german keyboard layout.